# Variable doesn't change its value during a for-loop statement

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

Was trying to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes method for finding all prime numbers up to 100. The product doesn't seem to change. What is the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{   
    int counter = 0;
    int multicand = 2;
    std::vector<int> non_prime;
    
    for (int product = multicand * 2; product < 100; multicand++){
        std::cout << product << '\n' << multicand << '\n';
        
        counter++;
        if (counter == 50) return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you change it?

Comment: maybe say ```product++``` in the ```std::cout```; and do you mean to increment multicand?

Comment: i specified the product in for-statement initialization

Comment: Because there are no statements to update `product`. You may want to change `multicand++` to `product = ++multicand * 2`.

Comment: thank you everyone, I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you are only incrementing the variable multicand.

When you do: `for (int product = multicand * 2; product < 100; multicand++){}`

You are saying to the compiler: Declare a variable called product and set it to multicand * 2 after that make a loop while product is less than 100, and at each cycle of the loop inclement the variable multicand by one.